# Excel - Code to selected from a list and pull data from a sheet with that name

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I am working in the following excel file:

[image]

How do I create an Index/Match that used the value selected in D1 and goes to that sheet and places info from 1 cell into another?

For example:  In Cell A1, I want the data from GAN!A1 to appear there when GAN is selected.

The formula will then be copied and pasted into A2 thru A5 accordingly.

Thanks in advance!  I have been researching Index() and Match() with no luck so far.

((Side Note:  The "Ping It!" button works by taking the IP addresses and storing them in a text file and then calling a program called "PingInfoView" and importing the addresses.  Very cool.))

-Dave

Comment: Use INDIRECT: `=INDIRECT("'" & D1 & "!A" & Row())`

Comment: I am getting a #REF, but I think it's because I need a closing '   ?

Comment: You rock.  Fixed it with :

=INDIRECT("'" & D1 & "'" & "!A" & ROW())